# can spring transaction manager able to manage 2 pc transaction?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I'm using 2 resources in my application **jms** and **database**. i've configured like below, i am doing a simple test in below order to check the break in system.

1. Insert uuid in DB.
2. Send uuid as message to jms queue.
3. Listen message on remote listener.
4. Check uuid is present in DB or not?

Here is fully working code : https://github.com/ameyjadiye/mq-fury

This way i just want to ensure that data always present in db when remote listener check it in db.

i'm running 1k messages on system and all is working fine as of now, is there any possibility that check can fail ? i am not managing db transaction explicitly, do i need to do some more settings here ?

```
<bean id = "messageListenerContainer2" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="real_queue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="jmsMessageListener2"/>
    <property name="cacheLevel" value="1"/>
    <property name="concurrency" value="5-5" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jmsTransactionManager"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
  </bean>
     <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
      </bean>

     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.102:3306/test" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="r00T" />
        </bean>
```

This is a stand alone application in spring, tried with **ChainedTrnsactionManager** but it makes system slow

Comment: You need to configure a `JTATransactionManager` to use 2PC. Maybe that's what is missing?

Comment: does question needs more information about configurations i made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration does not looks like supporting 2-phase commit transactions. When using Spring as transaction manager for 2PC, you would need to use [JtaTransactionManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) which would internally use the actual JTA transaction manager provided typically by JTA containers ( all EE compliant servers) or using standalone transaction managers such as [Bitrionix](https://github.com/bitronix/btm) or [Atomikos](http://www.atomikos.com/Main/WebHome). For a sample example take a look [here](https://github.com/nielspeter/atomikos-jta-jpa-jms-example).

Comment: its simple spring application, not deploying on any EE server, also how JTAtransactionManager is different than chainedTransactionManager ?

Comment: @Arney Jadiye: From the docs: PlatformTransactionManager implementation that orchestrates transaction creation, commits and rollbacks to a list of delegates. **Using this implementation assumes that errors causing a transaction rollback will usually happen before the transaction completion or during the commit of the most inner PlatformTransactionManager.**. <end of javadoc> In a JTA Transaction manager/2PC the error can happen **anywhere**, and the whole transaction will be reverted. Don't want to sound patronizing, but do read the docs.

Comment: @Amey - When it comes to 2PC, Spring does not have actual capability to global transactions (aka XA transactions). This capability has already been perfected by external JTA transaction manager and Spring does not intend to reinvent the wheel. If your application is not running on EE server, you would need to use external TM's.